# How to give column name dynamically from string variable in sql alchemy filter?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to create query in sql alchemy filter, but column is(dynamic) in variable/specified in variable.

Original Query:

```
db_session.query(Notice).filter(Notice.subject.like("%" +query+ "%"))
```

I want to do query like this:

```
col_name='subject'
db_session.query(Notice).filter(Notice.col_name.like("%" +query+ "%"))
col_name='status'
status=0
db_session.query(Notice).filter(Notice.col_name != 1)
```

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Just use [getattr](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr) standard python library function to get an attribute by name:

```
col_name = 'subject'
db_session.query(Notice).filter(getattr(Notice, col_name).like("%" + query + "%"))
```

Comment: to my understanding "Notice" here is a python Class? as a sqlarchemy data model? As a table in the database??

Comment: `Notice` is a python class, and is a mapped `sqlalchemy` model. So in the first example from [Classical Mapping](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapping_styles.html#classical-mappings) it would be `User`, not `user`.

Answer (score 22):

In newer sqlalchemy version, it should be done this way:

```
Notice.__table__.c[col_name]
```

So:

```
(db_session
    .query(Notice)
    .filter(Notice.__table__.c[col_name].like("%" + query + "%")
)
```

Comment: I'm not convinced that anything here is specific to newer SQLAlchemy versions. What's your basis for that claim? What functionality here didn't exist in older versions?

Comment: Note that you can use `.columns` instead of `.c`, which is perhaps clearer.

Comment: This is not related to version. You're accessing the `Column` objects from the underlying `Table`, instead of the instrumented attributes of the mapped class. This might not even work, if the mapped attribute is named differently from the column.

Comment: I think your filter is missing a closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 4):

I tried @vans solution but it didn't work. I always got an AttributeError complaining that my table didn't have that column. What worked for me was `table.columns`:

```
getattr(Notice.columns,col_name)
```

Comment: This is because the question queries on an ORM mapped python class whereas you are querying on a `Table` instance.

Answer (score -3):

The accepted answer has a solution, but an outdated one.

SQLAlchemy 1.3 suggests putting all text filters in `text()`, joined with `and`.
[Docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#using-textual-sql)

Example: `session.query(User).filter(text("id<224")).order_by(text("id")).all()`

Another [example](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#using-text-fragments-inside-bigger-statements) from docs on a different query

```
>>> s = select([
...        text("users.fullname || ', ' || addresses.email_address AS title")
...     ]).\
...         where(
...             and_(
...                 text("users.id = addresses.user_id"),
...                 text("users.name BETWEEN 'm' AND 'z'"),
...                 text(
...                     "(addresses.email_address LIKE :x "
...                     "OR addresses.email_address LIKE :y)")
...             )
...         ).select_from(text('users, addresses'))
```

Comment: Make sure you're not vulnerable to SQL injection if you put dynamic things in the `text()`...

Comment: I think you missed the point of the question. Using SQL text and passing a model attribute name as a string are separate things. This Q/A seems mostly about the latter, and there's nothing outdated about the accepted answer.