# sqlalchemy make columns follow relationship with rules

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

How do I get attr to be the name of the column being checked and value the value of the column being checked?

models.py

```
class Dates(db.Model):
    username=db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True)
    apples = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    oranges = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    milk = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    bananas = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    beans = db.Column(db.DateTime)

    def is_expired(self, date)
        #I want attr to equal the column it is coming from
        #example if I typed Dates.apples.is_expired('2017-01-01')
        #I want attr to equal 'apples', that way Rules.rule brings back
        # the rule # associated with apples
        #I want value to be the date from Dates.apples
        a=Rules.query.filter_by(name=attr).first()
        if a.rule=='1':
            value=datetime.datetime.strptime(value, '%Y-%m-%d')
            date=datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d')
            for i in range(36):
                value=add_one_month(value)
            if date>value:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        elif a.rule=='2':
            value=datetime.datetime.strptime(value, '%Y-%m-%d')
            date=datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d')
            for i in range(12):
                value=add_one_month(value)
            if date>value:
                return True
            else:
                return False

    def __repr__(self):  # pragma: no cover
        return '<Mobility %r>' % (self.username)

class Rules(db.model)
    rule=db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name=db.Column(db.String(45))

    def __repr__(self):  # pragma: no cover
        return '<Mobility %r>' % (self.name)
```

Example of a call in another function:

```
user=Dates.query.filter_by(username='bob').first()
user.apples='2017-02-11'
if user.apples.is_expired('2017-04-12'):
    color=red
```

In this case attr='apples', value='2017=02-11'

Comment: there is no `attr` object known inside of `is_expired` method, maybe it should be `date`?

Comment: also your `a` object has type `Query`, not `Rules`, probably you've forgotten to add `.first()` like `a=Rules.query.filter_by(name=attr).first()`?

Comment: also where `value` object comes from (again inside of `is_expired` method)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to give column name dynamically from string variable in sql alchemy filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10251724/how-to-give-column-name-dynamically-from-string-variable-in-sql-alchemy-filter)

Comment: Stressing the word "possible". Your question is also a bit unclear as to what you're after. The unverifiable code example does not help.

Comment: Thanks for the .first() fix, I am trying to figure out how to get attr and value to work the way I want. Ideally attr would return the value 'apples' if I were to call Dates.apples.is_expired(some date) and value would return the date stored in Dates.apples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have `attr` inside the function, you should pass it as a parameter.
This is not about SQLAlchemy actually - python object don't work the way you try to use it here: `object.attr.method()` is not a valid way to call `object`'s method.

Instead you need something like `user.is_expired('apples', '2017-04-12')`. Inside the method you can get the field value as `getattr(self, attr_name)`, assuming that you change the method signature to `def is_expired(self, attr_name, date)`.