# flask-sqlalchemy filter using text array

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to filter my flask-sqlalchemy query via strings. My procedure for creating the string results in the following array:

```
["user.name == 'Sid'", "user.role == 'admin'"]
```

It gets formed with something like this:

```
for i in myarray:
    filter_string = "%s.%s == '%s'" % (self.model.__tablename__, i[0], i[2])
    or_filters.append(filter_string)
```

Here is how I'm using it:

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
...
class myclass:
  def __init(self, model):
    self.model = model
    self.q = db.session.query(self.model)

  def get(self, cfg):
    ...
    # the following line works
    myfilter = [User.name == 'Sid', User.role == 'admin']
    # the following line does not work, but I need it to. How to modify into the line above?
    myfilter = ["user.name == 'Sid'", "user.role == 'admin'"]
    if myfilter is not None:
      self.q = self.apply_filter(myfilter)

    items = self.q.all()
    return items

  def apply_filter(self, ftr):
    self.q.filter(or_(*ftr))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to give column name dynamically from string variable in sql alchemy filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10251724/how-to-give-column-name-dynamically-from-string-variable-in-sql-alchemy-filter)

Comment: This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You have the model and you have the desired attribute name. Use `or_filters.append(getattr(self.model, i[0]) == i[2])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ilja had a good solution

```
myfilter = getattr(self.model, i[0]).is_(i[2])
if myfilter is not None:
  self.q = self.apply_filter(myfilter)
```