# Is there a way to parse in a variable name into a sqlalchemy column name?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a function that returns a column from a table that looks something like this:

```
def getCol(x,y):
    q = db.session.query(table.x, table.y)
    return q
```

However python does not recognize the individual variable in table.x, and just says it can't find column x. When x would really be a variable.

Thanks

Comment: try `table.c.x`, `table.c.y`

Comment: what does the .c do?

Comment: c stands for "column". Read the doc at http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#selecting

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10251724/how-to-give-column-name-dynamically-from-string-variable-in-sql-alchemy-filter