# SQLAlchemy with_entities with dynamic inputs

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

how can I provide the `with_entities` option with dynamic input?

At the moment I have to do this:

```
columns = [DataModel.col1, DataModel.col2, ...]
data = DataModel.query.order_by(DataModel.id.desc()).with_entities(*columns).first()
```

But what should I do, if I get the `col` name as `query-string parameters` and have to define it dynamically?

**EDIT EDIT EDIT**
solved it this way:
In my model I define the classmethod:

```
@classmethod
def find_by_filter(cls, attr):
    search_columns = [getattr(cls, i) for i in attr]

    return cls.query.order_by(cls.id.desc()).with_entities(*search_columns).first()
```

and then I can call it from my Rest API this way:

```
liste = ["column 1", "column2", "column3", "column4"]

data = DataModel.find_by_filter(liste)
```

Comment: Did you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10251724/how-to-give-column-name-dynamically-from-string-variable-in-sql-alchemy-filter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to give column name dynamically from string variable in sql alchemy filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10251724/how-to-give-column-name-dynamically-from-string-variable-in-sql-alchemy-filter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same challenge and this is how I solved it.
`columns` is just a CSV string eg `"field1,field2,field3"`
Could be further condensed but this is enough for readability.

```
def pick_Columns(modelClass, columns):
  if len(columns) == 0:
    return None

  colArray = columns.split(',')
  modelObjects = [eval(f'{modelClass.__name__}.{col}') for col in colArray]
  return modelObjects


def Get_Data(**kwargs):
  retVal = kwargs['db'].query(m_DataModel)

  if kwargs.get('columns', None) is not None:
    colObj = pick_Columns(m_DataModel, kwargs['columns'])
    retVal = retVal.with_entities(*colObj)
    retVal = [row._asdict() for row in retVal.all()] # with_entities returns a tuple instead of dict. Remove this line if that's what you want

  else:
    retVal = retVal.all()

  return retVal
```