# SQLAlchemy set columnname with for loop

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2

How can i use a variable as the column name, when adding new entries to the table. I have a HTML form which posts the entered values.  My code is as follows

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Budget(db.Model):
    id=db.Column("id", db.Integer, primary_key=True) 
    Casenumber=db.Column("Casenumber", db.Integer)
    Project=db.Column("Project", db.String(30)) 
    Price=db.Column("Price", db.Integer)     

attributes=["Casenumber","Project","Price"]
        
        for i in attributes:     
            new_entry=request.form.get(i)
            db_entry=Budget(i=new_entry)
            db.session.add(db_entry)
        db.session.commit()
```

I get this TypeError: 'i' is an invalid keyword argument for Budget. How do i get to read the value of i i.e "Casenumber" instead of just i.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to give column name dynamically from string variable in sql alchemy filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10251724/how-to-give-column-name-dynamically-from-string-variable-in-sql-alchemy-filter)

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out

```
class Budget(db.Model):
    id=db.Column("id", db.Integer, primary_key=True) 
    Casenumber=db.Column("Casenumber", db.Integer)
    Project=db.Column("Project", db.String(30)) 
    Price=db.Column("Price", db.Integer)     

attributes=["Casenumber","Project","Price"]
        new_entry=Budget()
        for i in attributes:   
            setattr(new_entry, i,request.form.get(i))
        db.session.add(new_entry)   
        db.session.commit()
```